# Laravel 4 Custom Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-4

I have an array (converted from Json) and I wish to paginate over it. I am fairly new to Laravel and the docs are usually great, however on the odd occasion they lack a little.

My code to create the pagination instance is:

```
$plugin_return = Paginator::make($plugin, count($plugin), 20);
```

However when I `@foreach` over it in my view it is returning a few thousand lines instead of the 20 that I am wanted (and stating in the code above).

`$plugin_return->count()` returns `int(9027)`

I have also tried `$plugin_return->getItems()`, which also returns all 9027 elements.
`$plugin_return->getPerPage()` returns `int(20)`

Is this a bug or am I failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to do this:

```
 $plugin_return = Paginator::make($plugin, count($plugin), 20);

 foreach($plugin_return->getCollection()->all() as $plugin)
      $plugin-> something;
 endforeach

 $plugin_return->links();
```

Comment: That is still returning all 9027 elements.

Comment: and those 9027 items is the total array size right?

Comment: Correct.


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => Stop users swearing

            [plugin_name] => NoSwear
            [slug] => a5h73y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => 
            [plugin_name] => AaaaahDeath
            [slug] => aaaaahdeath
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [description] => aAntiSpam alles via Config
            [plugin_name] => aAntiSpam
            [slug] => aantispam
        )
)

Thats an example of the array..

Comment: How about doing it with plain php using array_chunk() ?

Comment: Oh and take a look at this page. i think it may solve your problem.
http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/using-illuminates-paginator-with-an-array-instead-of-eloquent

Comment: Thanks, just got round to checking this out. The link you posted worked after some modifications, I'll edit your answer and then mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please read more about paginator from here : http://culttt.com/2014/02/24/working-pagination-laravel-4/ It has a great example regarding how to work with it.

Basically, when you iterate over your $plugin_return , the paginator returns all your $plugins. What you need is, as you said, `$plugin_return->getPerPage()` and iterate over it, it's not a bug, it's how Paginator works

Usually you will have your model, for example Plugin model, and you will run something like :

```
Plugin::paginate(10);
```

Basically eliminating the Paginator, which is used more for customisation

Diggin up some more on simple Paginator, you will need to build the view by yourself.
[Look here for an example](http://codingswag.ghost.io/custom-pagination-in-laravel-4/)

In the first link, the author replicated the functionality provided by the Model, by overriding the getByPage.

Comment: Don't think I fully understand, its running an int and not an array?

Comment: I edited the answer, with how i think, most probably you would want to do this

Comment: I wish I could do it the easy way, unfortunately I am grabbing an external JSON file from an external server and am wanting to process that array.

Comment: Updated with a link to an example